# How to inquire about current value of MAX_EXECUTION_TIME

Tags: mysql, query-timeout

I understand that I can set the value of the global MAX_EXECUTION_TIME by running (from mysql client):

```
SET GLOBAL MAX_EXECUTION_TIME
```

But how do I just inquire its value?

GET instead of SET does not seem to accomplish that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'MAX_EXECUTION_TIME'` or `select @@max_execution_time` for retrieval.

"The execution timeout for SELECT statements, in milliseconds. If the value is 0, timeouts are NOT enabled." per [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_execution_time).